# Getting pixel amount of Scrolling in an Overflow Hidden Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I wish to be able to toggle a class for the `body` when there is a large amount of scroll in the page, but there is a catch: its a full-sized, hidden overflow, single page.

I tried the simple:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000){
    $('body').addClass( "endScroll");
}
else {
    $('body').removeClass("endScroll");
}
```

I tried this method to add the class `endScroll` after the page has been scrolled after 1000 pixels, however, it does not work because since it is a single screen with overflow hidden, there is no actual scroll from top. (To better explain, there is an animation going on while the user scrolls)

So I tried this method:

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if (delta < 0) {
        $('body').addClass("endScroll");
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        $('body').removeClass("endScroll");
    }

});
```

While it actually works, adding the class, it does as soon as the user scroll once. I can't figure a way to make it toggle the class after 1000 pixels have been scrolled.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I think this is closer to what you're looking for. You need a tracking variable to see how much the user has scrolled:

```
var scrollVal = 0;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    scrollVal += e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;        
    if (scrollVal > 0) scrollVal = 0;     

    console.log(scrollVal);        
    if (scrollVal < -1000) {
        $('body').addClass( "endScroll");
    }else {
        $('body').removeClass("endScroll");
    }    
});
```

EDIT 2: Firefox compatibility:

```
var scrollVal = 0;
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
$(document).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e) {
    var offset = -1 * e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (mousewheelevt == "DOMMouseScroll"){
      offset = e.originalEvent.layerY - e.originalEvent.clientY;
    }
    scrollVal += offset;        
    if (scrollVal < 0) scrollVal = 0;
    console.log(scrollVal);        
    if (scrollVal > 1000) {
        $('body').addClass( "endScroll");
    }else {
        $('body').removeClass("endScroll");
    }    
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Is 'body' the scrolling container? Or is it another div below that?

Comment: The body has `overflow: hidden`. So there is no actual scroll in the site. As the user scrolls, some animations happen in the page.

Comment: Picture a static page. As the user scrolls down, some pictures fall into the page, but the page never scrolls down.

Comment: I think its almost there! It kind of works now. I start scrolling and the desired effect pops up. As I continue to scroll down, the effect continues (as desired). But with a single scroll up, doesn't matter how far I am, the class toggles back and the effect goes away. I need it to go back ONLY if I'm under 1000px.

Comment: Gotcha. I removed the line that keeps the value capped

Comment: Now its perfect! Thank you very much, Freeze! :)

Comment: Hey! Just one more thing, if you think you could help me. This solution seems to work perfectly in chrome, but it does not work in Firefox. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think FF supports that event. You can use: var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" to test: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

Comment: Yes. I tested and it detects the mouse scroll. But is there anyway to make the same thing work on FF? Is there a way to adapt: "DOMMouseScroll" to same formula?

Comment: It looks like you can use the layerY of the event object as the offset if mousewheelevt == 'DOMMouseScroll'. That should do it.

Comment: Would you please show me how? I'm trying with no avail.

Comment: I modified but you'll have to tweak.

Comment: Thanks Freeze! It works well now! I think I can handle the tweaks! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Just scroll it to 1000px and see the background will be red if you scroll up it will be again black

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >  1000){
        $(".scroll-div").addClass('scroll-div-red');
    }
    else{
    $(".scroll-div").removeClass('scroll-div-red');   
    }
});
```

```css
.scroll-div{
  background:#000;
  height:1500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.scroll-div-red.scroll-div{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-div">

</div>
```